# Are the SINNER and Erased qualities compatible?

Tags: character-creation, shadowrun-sr5

Is the SINNER negative quality (Core Rulebook p.84-85) compatible with the Erased positive quality (Run Faster p.146)?

> [ERASED] those who had a SIN but had it actively and thoroughly erased

For example with a corporate SIN would it make sense that a shadowrunner still pays taxes to the corporation she works for but can't be found in the registries?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I can recall no rule that exactly says something about it.

As a GM I wouldn't allow this for my players, as it's a exclusion. If your character is erased, there are not data about him. But as a Sinner there are legally stored data about him. You can only have one of them.

Esp. in you example I don't see why that should work. If the SC is legally paying taxes, that will be save. With erased all information about that would be erased soon after. Therefore there would be no information that he paid the taxes and therefore it would be as if he hadn't payed them in the first place.

With that he has no disadvantage from it and therefore I wouldn't let him get points for it.

On the other hand you could work all of that in a story to justify it: The SC thinks he has a legal SIN and doesn't know that he is erased (jet). Therefore he legally pays his taxes and all the other good stuff, but there is never a record of it. He probably has a fake SIN, as it's smart for a runner that he usually uses. But every time he wants to do something with his legal SIN he has problems cause there is no real SIN behind that. In that case I'd be willing to let him take that disadvantages as it's a variation that still get's him trouble and might result in some funny scenes.

Answer (score 1):

Not sure it's exclusive since within "Erased" it's said someone is cleaning that you do not want to be kept/known. Your "erased" SIN is finally still a true but Virgin SIN.

So, with Sinner, you have a true ID that can be "erased" from bad contains. You can be your SIN.

However, I will in this case recommend to have also a fake SIN in order to run and a true SIN that is to be preserved from bad issues. So you will be your fake SIN in missions (or bad things) and also your true (and preserved) SIN in society.